# How can we make a web page/session load into another user's browser (for troubleshooting purposes)?

Tags: session, sharing, mirroring

I'm a product designer trying to solve this problem:

**"As an admin (support person) I want to allow a user of a specific software platform (SAAS) to share or mirror their session to me so I can watch what they're doing - WITHOUT using a typical screen share application."**

Problems:

1. Admins on our platform need to remotely assist users who are stuck, are seeing errors or otherwise confused in using the system.
2. Due to the secure nature of our industry, having customers install apps, especially screen-sharing apps, is completely out of the question. We're looking for a self-contained solution.

> This session-sharing would be confined to our SAAS platform, not (necessarily) anything else in the user's browser.

**What if the admin could look up the user's profile (existing capability) AND, if they're online, request the user to share their session - and the system's server could serve the same pages to the user AND to the admin?**

**Sample Scenario:**
Suppose you're using a new web-based platform called "MyMovies." You see an error or you're confused about how something works so you contact their support. A support person responds, letting you know they want to see your MyMovies session (and won't see anything else on your screen). A new prompt appears asking you to accept the support person's request to view your MyMovies session. The support person is able to see your session (and, ideally, take control to point-and-click or touch-and-swipe) to help resolve your issue. At no time can they see what's in other browser tabs or windows or anything else open in your device or computer.

My dev team has asked me to research how we might accomplish this, thus I'm doing research on the web and looking for ideas and suggestions. They'd prefer to build (vs. buy). Since we control the servers on which our saas application is built, we have some flexibility.

Thank you.